# MPU6050 Read Accel,Gyro AND Magnetometer?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino and the MPU6050 Board.
I need a sketch to read the Sensorvalues of Accel, Gyro and Compass/Magnetometer.

The Problem is:
The Accel and Gyro sensor are on the same chip and the Magnetometer on a second chip.

I found only sketches for reading out gyro and accel or only magnetometer/compass

but i need something to read out all tree sensors.

help?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you'll need to provide more detail. Not sure what board you have, however:

1. Check out Jeff Rowberg's excellent library for the MPU6050 and explanation how to read each sensor - gyroscope, accelerometer and magnetometer.
2. If you're using one of the 9DOF/ 10DOF boards with MPU6050 e.g. gy-86 you'll need to disable the I2C Master Mode and Sleep Mode, and enable I2C Bypass Mode:

`mpu.setI2CMasterModeEnabled(false);
mpu.setI2CBypassEnabled(true);
mpu.setSleepEnabled(false);`